# Do i need to remove the jumper wire from my 14 kw gen before hooking up i have no transfer switch i

Tags: generator

I am hooking up a 14 kw kohler without a transfer switch i am completely off grid do i remove the jumper from neutral to ground and then hook up all four wires

Comment: Yes remove the jumper

Comment: Is your panel set up as a main panel or as a subpanel?